# How to write a left join with subquery in Laravel 5.1

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, laravel-5.1, laravel-query-builder

I have the following subquery:

```
$subQuery = Role::join('role_user', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->join('users', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('roles.name', '=', 'Admin')
        ->select('users.id', 'roles.name')->get();
```

How do I can i add it to a left join in my main query the following doesn't work
as it doesn't recognise $subQuery.id becuase its a collection with 3 records.:

```
 $users = User::join('profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->leftJoin($subQuery, 'users.id', '=', $subQuery.id)
        ->select('users.*', 'profiles.*', '$subQuery.name as admin' )
        ->get();
```